# download file/s from OneDrive with Powershell

Tags: powershell, onedrive

New to OneDrive and fairly new to Powershell (under 1 yr experience). Need to understand how to download/copy files from OneDrive down to local server/PC. What extra's do I need, what approach works best?

P.S I've seen posts stating to use OneDrive SDK but I honestly have no idea what that is or how to use it. Is Powershell the best option if not what works best and fairly easy to learn?

Comment: For additional reference a sister office changed the way they provide PDF files to us from dragging and dropping onto shared folder to instead them dragging into OneDrive shared folder. Our existing powershell script will still be in use I'm just going to add a step to first grab the files from OneDrive but that's where my drive is coming to a halt! HELP!

Comment: Do you know the URL of the file you want to download?

Comment: Have a look at this [OneDrive Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/OneDrive/2.1.1).  I've never used it, but it's worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you. I had to manually download the package and import it into my elevated PS Session. This probably would have worked but turns out the site i was given is not the admin site. Once I get that I should be able to accomplish my task. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess this depends on how big your OneDrive environment is.
You can of course sync OneDrive on the local pc and access the files through file explorer.
These files can be reached programmatically through PowerShell.

As far as I know your OneDrive environment will correspond with SharePoint. 
You can therefore reach the files through the `PnPOnline`Cmdlets if you wish.

Comment: Thanks I started googling PnPOnline Cmdlets and found this.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline/3.4.1812.0

however I couldn't run the Install-Module command and rather had to go the manual rout specified in the above article...

Comment: Are you able to verify that the version is correct?

Comment: my powershell version?
$psversiontable says "PSVersion                      5.1.14393.2636"

I think I discovered my issue, I didn't have the correct admin sharepoint site but once I did have the correct admin site i get (401) Unauthorized error. Request for access sent...

Comment: I was thinking more in the lines of Sharepoint-module version. You can check this by running the Get-Installedmodule Cmdlet. My own version is 3.2.1810.0. 
Do you have MFA enabled on the admin-account you're connecting with? That could explain the error you're getting.

Comment: Ran Get-Installedmodule and got "Get-Installedmodule : The term 'Get-Installedmodule' is not recognized..." so I guess Sharepoint module didn't install. Going to reattempt to install.

What is MFA so I can check and see. In our environment we have PIV Cards and two accounts one "regular" and one "premium" kidding "Elevated" I have to put in my Elevated Credentials to run as administrator so things get a bit confusing...

Comment: MFA is Multi-Factor Authentication, for example using an authenticator App on your phone. I have experienced a couple of problems related to connecting to Sharepoint through PowerShell using MFA.

Comment: oh yes MFA duh, yes I have two accounts one Elevated and just a regular account and throw in the PIV card further complicates things. I finally was able to get past my main hurdle by not running "Install-Module" but rather using the method in the link below to "Import-Module" after downloading the packages and pointing the import to that folder. I hope I have to only do this once but we'll see what further testing turns up. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Great news Tmont, I'm glad to have helped!