# How to programmatically download a file from teams (onedrive)?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, microsoft-teams, onedrive

There is an excel file in teams (OneDrive). It has been shared with everyone. I have got the link.

When I paste the link into the browser, then it opens the excel file.

I want to download this file onto my local computer every hour. For this I tried using the SSIS (SQL server integration services) but there is no task that is supporting the download.

I want to ask whether it is possible to and how to programmatically download this file for example using PowerShell or .Net code?

Here is what I tried:

```
$source = 'file link url' 
$destination = 'C:\Test\test1.xlsx'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source -OutFile $destination
```

The file called test1.xlsx gets created in the C:\Test folder but I cannot open it. Error is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Onedrive has [an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content?view=odsp-graph-online).

Comment: Sync Onedrive into a local directory and pick the file up from there?

Comment: Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http | Also refer this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714384/download-file-s-from-onedrive-with-powershell

Comment: @vonPryz - can I sync a file shared with me via link, to a local directory? Any reference please?

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive is actually a flavour of SharePoint behind the scenes, so you can use various SharePoint tools to periodically download the file. For PowerShell, you can use the `Get-PnPFile` option (see [here](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPFile.html)), part of the [PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/index.html) package (a joint community+Microsoft open source project). In the C# world, there's a PnP option as well, with the [PnP Core SDK](https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/).

Be aware, that to have this run in an automated fashion, and depending on how your Microsoft 365 Tenant is configured, you might need an Azure AD "Application". This will enable your app (PowerShell or C#) to connect without an interactive, logged in user.